# awk script always prints sum=0

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I'm sorry if the question might be silly, but I am totally new to awk scripting.
What I want to do is to calculate and print the usage of CPU and memory by the user "root".
I wrote this bash script which executes an awk script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ps aux > processi.txt
echo Lancio script3.awk
awk -f script3.awk processi.txt
```

and the awk script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN{
print "Inizio script\n"
cpu=0
mem=0
}

/root/{
    printf("Cpu usata da root loop=%.1f, memoria=%.1f\n",$3,$4)

        cpu=cpu+$3
        mem=mem+$4
}

END{
printf("Cpu usata da root=%.1f, memoria=%.1f\n",$cpu,$mem)
print "\nFine script\n"
}
```

But the print from the `END` is `0`, while in `/root/` is correct.
Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` isn't used to expand variables in `awk`, where it signals the expansion of a particular input field whose number is contained in the given variable. That is, if `cpu=3`, then `$cpu` is equivalent to `$3`. Just use the variable name by itself.

```
END {
  printf("Cpu usata da root=%.1f, memoria=%.1f\n", cpu, mem)
  print "\nFine script\n"
}
```

Comment: @rafc always remember - **awk is not shell**. Awk syntax is far more similar to C than it is so shell.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, syntactically it's legal, although probably nearly useless inside an `END` block. But agreed, for the intended use it cannot be used.

Comment: Just adding some info: Inside an END block the behavior related to field numbers is undefined by POSIX. So when `cpu=3` then `$cpu` = `$3` as you state but on a per-awk basis the value of `$3` in the END section might be value of the 3rd field of the last record read or it might be the NULL string or it could be anything else. The only thing POSIX mandates in the END section wrt values related to the last record read is that `NF` be the number of fields in that last record read but it's up to each awk to decide what $0, $1, etc. should contain and some choose NULL.

Comment: Thanks; I didn't bother looking that up, and just assumed it would preserve the last value.

Answer (score 2):

The initial approach seems to be redundant. Use can extract the needed fields for the user name `root` directly by `ps` options:

The whole job:

```
ps U root -eo  %cpu,%mem --no-header | awk 'BEGIN{ print "Inizio script\n" }
    { printf("Cpu usata da root loop=%.1f, memoria=%.1f\n",$1,$2); cpu+=$1; mem+=$2; }
    END { printf("Cpu usata da root=%.1f, memoria=%.1f\n\nFine script\n", cpu, mem) }'
```

---

- `U root` - select data only for the user name `root`
- `-eo  %cpu,%mem` - output only `cpu` and `mem` field values

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't address your question per se, an additional suggestion that won't fit in a comment is: **formatting your code consistently will make your code easier to read and debug**.

Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    print "Inizio script\n"
    cpu = 0
    mem = 0
}

/root/ {
    printf("Cpu usata da root loop=%.1f, memoria=%.1f\n", $3, $4)

    cpu = cpu + $3
    mem = mem + $4
}

END {
    printf("Cpu usata da root=%.1f, memoria=%.1f\n", cpu, mem)
    print "\nFine script\n"
}
```

where I

- indented anything inside `{}` to the same level
- put spaces around operators like `=` and `+`
- put spaces between the block labels and the opening `{`
- put spaces after `,`s in your `printf()` arguments
- also removed the extraneous `$` mentioned in the other answer.